# Algorithm to divide server reboots to once a week

Tags: algorithm, powershell

Have to add functionality to a script I am working on that will set a variable number of servers in a citrix farm and then setting them to reboot only once a week.   So if there are 2 servers, it will set them to reboot on saturdays and sundays.  if there are 7, it will go through the week.  If there are 10, it will set 2 to reboot on 3 of the days, 1 the rest of the week.   Just looking for a basic algorithm on how this as me and a coworker keep over thinking it and coming up with logic that seems too complicated.

Comment: Is it that you want to reboot each server once per week, and you want to make sure that the maximum total number of reboots per day is as small as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
$Servers = 1..10 |% {"Server$_"}

$Servers |
foreach {"$_ reboots on $([DayOfWeek]($i++%7))"}

Server1 reboots on Sunday
Server2 reboots on Monday
Server3 reboots on Tuesday
Server4 reboots on Wednesday
Server5 reboots on Thursday
Server6 reboots on Friday
Server7 reboots on Saturday
Server8 reboots on Sunday
Server9 reboots on Monday
Server10 reboots on Tuesday
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#$computerlist = Get-Content myservers.txt
$computerlist = 1..11 | % { "Server$_" }

$day = 1

$computerlist | ForEach-Object {

    #[System.DayOfWeek] is an enum which goes from 0 to 6, so we subtract 1 from day-value.
    #Or you could use $day = 0 and if($day -eq 6) .... Depends on what you're going to do.
    "$_ should restart on day $([System.DayOfWeek]($day-1))"

    #Next day
    if($day -eq 7) { $day = 1 } else { $day++ }

}

Server1 should restart on day Sunday
Server2 should restart on day Monday
Server3 should restart on day Tuesday
Server4 should restart on day Wednesday
Server5 should restart on day Thursday
Server6 should restart on day Friday
Server7 should restart on day Saturday
Server8 should restart on day Sunday
Server9 should restart on day Monday
Server10 should restart on day Tuesday
Server11 should restart on day Wednesday
```